# couchDB restore error : Missing JSON list of 'docs'

Tags: json, couchdb

when copying a database from one host to another I get the folowing error : ***Missing JSON list of 'docs'***

Here is what I do :

```
source> curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/cozy/_all_docs?include_docs=true > cozy.dump

destination> curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/cozy 
{"ok":true}

destination> curl -d @cozy.dump -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5984/cozy/_bulk_docs 
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Missing JSON list of 'docs'"}
```

any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Problem comes from different couchdb versions source is 1.2.1 target is 1.4

Comment: I got same error. Dump was from 1.2, but I have 1.4. How did you fix that?

Comment: @rusllonrails You change "rows" in your dump to "docs" and it should be able to be pushed to /<dbname>/_bulk_docs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is, indeed, a problem with versions.

Fortunately it is fairly easy to fix: just change the first line in the dump, eg.

```
{"total_rows": 8244, "offset": 0, "rows": [
```

to

```
{"docs": [
```

The dumps can now be used in the later versions.

Comment: If you have a folder (ie. `dumps`) containing dumps and you want to update all of these dumps, you can use `find dumps -type f -exec sed -i '1s/.*/{"docs":[/' {} \;`. This replaces the first line, as described in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I am still posting an answer in case some one else is looking for the solution. The bulk docs `api` accepts the request in a certain form.

`{docs:[{},{},{}]}`

The docs key must contain an array of documents to be bulk inserted. What op did with

`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/cozy/_all_docs?include_docs=true > cozy.dump`

was that he simply stored the couchdb response of the format

```
{
 total_rows: 4,
 offset: 0,
 rows: [....]
}
```

into the cozy.dump file. As we have seen above this file is not in a form that can be consumed by the bulk docs api. Hence the error

`{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Missing JSON list of 'docs'"}`

Couchdb needs a JSON list of `docs` to perform the bulk insert.

Another point to be noted here is that if you supply an `_id` and `_rev` parameter couchdb performs a bulk update rather than a bulk insert. If you just want to copy one database to another use http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication

Comment: The source database name is reported as illegal (due to contain an underscore). I'm not an admin to rename, so I need to export and then import huge dump file via curl. I tried to use the trick you mentioned. But it still says `{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Missing JSON list of 'docs'"}`